# How to access a dynamically created CheckBox event state in another eventhandler method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dynamically created an array of checkboxes in a button1 click event. Now I want to check its checked property in another button2 click event. Since the check box controls are dynamically created at runtime, I am not able to access it in button2 click event. Please anybody help me with a solution for this.

```
public void Display(ref string[] strDmn, ref string[][] strAvblty)
{
    ch = new CheckBox[cntExt / 2];
    strDomInfo = new string[cntExt / 2];
    Table t = new Table();
    t.Caption = "Domain Availablity";
    t.BorderWidth = 1;
    TableRow tr;
    TableCell tc;
    System.Drawing.ColorConverter colConvert = new ColorConverter();

    for (int i = 0; i < (strDmn.Length); i++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < ((strAvblty[i].Length) / 2); l++)
        {
            tr = new TableRow();
            tr.BackColor = (System.Drawing.Color)colConvert.ConvertFromString("#F0E8FF");
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                //string k = strAvblty[i][(i * 2 + 1)];
                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Width = 300;
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 0:
                        ch[k - 1] = new CheckBox();
                        strDomInfo[k - 1] = strDmn[i] + "." + strAvblty[i][(l * 2)];
                        if (strAvblty[i][(l * 2) + 1] == "available")
                        { }
                        else { ch[k - 1].Enabled = false; }
                        tc.Controls.Add(ch[k - 1]);
                        break;
                    case 1: tc.Text = strDmn[i];
                        break;
                    case 2: tc.Text = strAvblty[i][(l * 2)];
                        break;
                    case 3: tc.Text = strAvblty[i][(l * 2) + 1];
                        break;
                }
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            }
            t.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
    // desiredPanel is your panel
    Panel1.Controls.Add(t);
}

protected void btnAdd2Cart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //******I have get the boolen check property here ******
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create these checkboxes in the `Page_Init` and they should be recreated on postback. Then you will be able to get the values in the `Button2's click handler`

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Create here
}
```